# How to vertically/horizontally center a CSS background-image with padding

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this to center it vertically and horizontally:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(/icon.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

That works, but now I am trying to add padding. I would like to have 10px or 20px padding on all sides, so for mobile it has some padding. I've tried this:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(/icon.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

But the right and bottom go over the viewport, so scrolling occurs and it's not centered exactly anymore. I've also tried using margin. Wondering how to get this to work. I would like to use CSS background-image if possible, instead of `<img>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;`

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300) center center no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because CSS uses, by default, the content-box box-sizing method. It means that *width = content width + padding + border* and *height = content height + padding + border*.

You can switch to the border-box box-sizing method, that includes padding and border in width and height.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(/icon.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  padding: 20px;

  box-sizing: border-box; /* switches to border-box method */
}
```

I hope that helps you!